# What will happen if I call a normal function in asynchronous function in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, aiogram

I use the aiogram asynchronous library to write bots for Telegram, and also use SQLAlchemy for databases. The functions I use while working with aiogram are asynchronous, but the sqlalchemy functions and methods are not. What will happen in this case and is it normal to use synchronous functions in an asynchronous function? (translated by google)

Comment: The bots will not be responsive while the sqlalchemy functions are running.

Comment: is the execution of sqlalchemy functions fast? will this affect the overall performance of the bot? the bot itself is simple, there is no complex logic and long operations with the database

Comment: That you will have to determine yourself. If the functions are fast enough, you may not notice a difference.

Comment: understood. but anyway, what is the way to solve this problem? is it even possible?

Comment: That's explained in the general case in the answer to the other question I've linked. But, more specifically, I'm pretty sure SQLAlchemy also has an asynchronous interface.